# Report Server Web Service: Connecting Subscription to schedule

Tags: c#, wcf, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm currently in the process of developing a front facing ASP application for a client which is wired up to the ReportService2010.asmx web service. We are using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have figured out how to fetch all schedules and create them on our end through the interface, but I can't figure out how to then create a subscription that is then connected to that schedule so that it runs at the time.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that unless some custom assemblies are added to the report server, subscriptions do not connect to schedules and are two different things.